# Doing some task afterEach describe in protractor with selenium server with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor

I want to do something after each describe(not after each testcase) and before each describe, is there any way to do this? i have require something like after block like afterEach block, please help...

Comment: Hi nilsk,is there any mistake in my question or something else

Comment: just the unnecessary use of code block ;) wasn't my downvote. btw: i don't undestand the last sentence in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doing something aftereach describe in protractor with selenium server with angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415507/doing-something-aftereach-describe-in-protractor-with-selenium-server-with-angul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using **jasmine-beforeall** nodejs module 
we can use beforeAll and afterAll for each describe

https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll