# Doing something aftereach describe in protractor with selenium server with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I want to do something after each describe(not after each testcase) and before each describe, is there any way to do this?  I have tried below format, but it gives me error that, before and after not defined, is it possible to do sometask before and after of each describe:

```
describe('testcase', function () {
    before(function () {
        --------------
    })
    beforeEach(function () {
       -----------------
    })
    afterEach(function () {
        --------------
    })
    after(function () {
        -----------------
    })
    it('task1', function () {
             -----------

    })it('task2', function () {
                  ------------------
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want [`beforeAll` and `afterAll`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown) which were introduced in `jasmine 2.1`:

> The beforeAll function is called only once before all the specs in
>   describe are run, and the afterAll function is called after all specs
>   finish. These functions can be used to speed up test suites with
>   expensive setup and teardown.

For the older `jasmine` versions, the same can be done with the help of [`jasmine-beforeAll` package](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll).

Comment: Hi alecxe,I am using jasmine of "version": "2.0.4", therefore i have installed jasmine-beforeall using sudo npm install jasmine-beforeall, and it is installed and its version is "0.1.1", but then i have used  beforeAll(function () {
        console.log("Top Before All");
    });
    afterAll(function () {
        console.log("Top after all");
    });, but it gives me error ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined, what other changes I have require to do, is there any other change in spec or conf file..please help

Comment: @RajitGarg what if you add `require('jasmine-beforeall');` at the top of your test?

Comment: I have now installed newer version of jasmine "version": "2.1.1" and still found the same error, beforeAll is not defined, please suggest...

Comment: Thank you alecxe , THis is working now, by require('jasmine-beforeall');