# Protractor check console for errors after action

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In my test I need to check if there are errors in the console after clicking a button. But the only errors I get are from the login page, then when the page loads after that. But nothing after the button click, and I know there are errors happening. And if there's not errors, there are logs. My function doesn't seem to capture those either. It's pretty frustrating. Here's my code. (I have the login code in my `config.js` file.)

```
function checkConsoleErrors() {
  browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function (browserLog) {
    if (browserLog.length) {
      browserLog.forEach(function(log){
        var error = log.level.value > 900;
        if(error) {
          console.error('ERROR: ', log.message);
          if (log.timestamp > timestamp) { 
            expect(error).toBeFalsy(); //only check for errors after the button click
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

describe('Errors', function() {
  afterEach(function() {
    checkConsoleErrors();
  });
  it('should have no errors', function() {
    //code here
    btn.click();
    timestamp = moment().valueOf(); //capture the time the button was clicked
    browser.sleep(10000); //wait
  });
});
```

Am I missing something? Is there a different/better way to do this?

Comment: try @alecxe 's answer from here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415507/doing-something-aftereach-describe-in-protractor-with-selenium-server-with-angul

Comment: i don't see how changing from `afterEach` to `afterAll` will have a different effect

Comment: Have you tried to use the console plugin built-in into protractor? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe yes i have, i didn't help much. It would pass when there were errors, even when marking failOnWarning and failOnError as true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for errors only after button click event, then you can write your `checkConsoleErrors()` function inside click event's promise instead of `afterEach()`. Here's how -

```
btn.click().then(function(){
    timestamp = moment().valueOf();
    browser.sleep(10000);
    checkConsoleErrors();
});
```

The [error log level](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#Log_Levels) values that browser gives back to console are usually `800` *(for info)* and `900` *(for warning)*, so your code doesn't print anything as you are checking for values above `900`. Levels above 900 are severe messages which display when fatal errors occur (ex, execution stopped because of a package issue, invalid path, etc). To see for error that your execution creates adjust the levels `>=900` to show the required messages. Hope this helps.

Comment: this seems like it would work. but i think its just the website being weird. :/ Also I forgot to mention that for when checking for non errors i did rewrite it so it showed all messages. But nothing besides warning and severe. Does it not check for regular `console.log`s?

Comment: You mean nothing beside warning and info. Your console errors are warnings from browser. Severe errors occur when execution stops. I believe it would not check for regular `console.log` until you explicitly specify it. Browser gives back logs after every command that selenium/protractor sends to it. External Reporters can help you print the errors to console for each test. Here's one - [Jasmine-Spec-Reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter).

Comment: i see. i do have a reporter i'm using as well.