# Log console errors using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I am trying to log console errors in protractor like this

log output is in format

```js
{
  level: {
    value: 900,
    name: 'WARNING'
  },
  message: 'message',
  timestamp: 1442090739962,
  type: ''
}, {
  level: {
    value: 800,
    name: 'INFO'
  },
  message: 'message',
  timestamp: 1442090740723,
  type: ''
}, {
  level: {
    value: 1000,
    name: 'ERROR'
  },
  message: 'error message',
  timestamp: 1442090740723,
  type: ''
},
```

I want to catch only errors so i have written test like this

```js
it('it should be detect console errors', function() {
  browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLogs) {
    // browserLogs is an array of objects with level and message fields
    browserLogs.forEach(function(log) {
      if (log.level.value > 900) { // it's an error log
        console.log('Browser console error!');
        console.log(log.message);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Problem is it's catching errors sometimes and sometimes not.

when i give wrong path to websocket and if there is an error then it is logging it. But When I give wrong path to `ng-include` and if there is a `404 error` in console then it's not logging.

I am using firefox for testing. Is this console plugin browser dependent or what?
Why it is showing different behaviour for console errors?

Comment: This post might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186902/protractor-check-console-for-errors-after-action.

Comment: Have you tried protractor's built-in console plugin?

Comment: I tried but it is printing  `Pass:  Console output` even if there are errors in console.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problems, so [I wrote wrapping functions](http://kurapov.ee/eng/qa/protractor_console_errors/)

```
injectConsoleTracing = function () {
    browser.executeScript('window.errs=typeof(errs)=="undefined" ? [] : window.errs; window.console.error = function(msg){window.errs.push(msg); }; ');
    browser.executeScript('window.logs=typeof(logs)=="undefined" ? [] : window.logs; window.console.log = function(msg){window.logs.push(msg); }; ');
};

expectNoConsoleErrors = function () {
    browser.executeScript('return window.errs;').then(function (v) {
        expect(v).toEqual([]);
    });
    browser.executeScript('return window.logs;').then(function (v) {
        expect(v).toEqual([]);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

800 is not greater  than 900 then how do you expect to catch the error,
it should be

```
if (log.level.value <= 900)
```

Comment: Sorry the log.level.value for error is 1000 not 800.

Answer (score 0):

In my Test Suite I use the following to check for Console Errors and display them if any are present:

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
    if (browserLog.length) {
        console.log('Browser console error!');
        console.error('log: ' + JSON.stringify(browserLog));
    }
});
```