# Is there a global browser object I can add a listener to catch all thrown errors?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, error-handling

I'm using Selenium to crawl an AngularJS site and would like to create a list of all thrown errors (the specific errors I'm actually interested in are these [lex errors](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%203-3%20%5B%5E%5D&p2=)). AngularJS exposes [$exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler) to overwrite exception handling behavior. But would rather stay away from modifying app code as much as possible as these are remote tests.

I'm using Firefox so [browser.manage().logs() fails](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5263). I suspect this question is closely related to  [Log console errors using protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546905/log-console-errors-using-protractor) - [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35335937/8920669).

I have tried `window.onerror` and `window.addEventListener('error', () => { ... });` but neither of them catch the thrown error.  I wonder if there is something that AngularJS is doing that blocks propagation to the window maybe?

My goal:

```js
window.thrownErrors = [];
[Some global object].throw = (error) => {
  console.error(error);
  window.thrownErrors.push(error);
}

throw new Error('throw test');
console.log(window.thrownErrors); // => ['throw test']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `useCapture` option when adding the event handler:

```
window.addEventListener('error', () => { ... }, true);
```

The third argument can be a `Boolean` indicating whether events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener *before* being dispatched to any `EventTarget` beneath it in the DOM tree. Events that are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture. Event bubbling and capturing are two ways of propagating events that occur in an element that is nested within another element, when both elements have registered a handle for that event. The event propagation mode determines the order in which elements receive the event. See [DOM Level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) and [JavaScript Event](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link4) order for a detailed explanation. If not specified, `useCapture` defaults to `false`.

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Unable to understand useCapture parameter in addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398290/unable-to-understand-usecapture-parameter-in-addeventlistener)
- [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: I think this is the right answer. The answer I found was with AngularJS. The framework didn't propagate the error to the window object. I ended up having to connect to the Angular object itself to get the error. Thank you for the answer.